# Formally state the bias-variance tradeoff & intuition

Tags: machine-learning, bias-variance-tradeoff

The following states the bias-variance dilemma formally:
$$\hat{\epsilon}_i = E[\epsilon^2] + \left[f - E[\hat{f}] \right]^2 + E\left[ \left(\hat{f} - E[\hat{f}] \right)^2 \right]$$
where this is interpreted as the sum of variation beyond model + model's bias^2 + model's variance. Now I've got two question concerning this:

- Firstly, I wonder how that is derived?
- Secondly, I want to know wether my intuition about it is right?

Start with the first one I can imagine that the starting point should be something like:

$$E[\hat{\epsilon}^2] = E\left[ (y - \hat{y})^2 \right] = E\left[ (f + \epsilon - \hat{f})^2 \right] = E\left[ ((f - \hat{f}) + \epsilon)^2 \right] = E\left[ (f - \hat{f})^2 + 2(f - \hat{f})\epsilon + \epsilon^2 \right] = E[(f - \hat{f})^2] + E[2(f - \hat{f})\epsilon] + E[\epsilon^2] = ...?$$

And my intuition:

There is not much we can do about the variation beyond the model, because it is introduced by the noise of the data(?). The bias vs. variance is basically a thing where we need to balance between over-fitting, but not generalizing (i.e. no bias but big variance). And under-fitting, which means the model might be too simple (biased) but does not vary so much when applied to new data (little variance). Is that how you think about it and interpret the equation?